# mysqli query with joins and blanks rows

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

i have been developing a website where i need to join two tables and then fetch the results .

i have a database with two tables

Table 1 named with mem
Table 2 Named with Payment

now table 1 has names and drawid of all the users on website
table 2 has payments of members with payment month and draw

Draw id and draw is same in both the tables.
User has to pay for every month, and any user can pay fr any month in advance .

Now i need to fetch the total number of memebrs which have not paid the amount till the month 4th with name and the total instalments he has paid.

here is the query that i am using right now. its working good but only issue is that it is also giving me some blank results .

```
 SELECT drawid,contact,dnd,mem.name, count(*) as numPayments,NULL 
 numPaidPayments ,NULL PAID_CONTACT,NULL NAME_PAID FROM mem 
 LEFT JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw) GROUP BY 
  drawid HAVING numPayments < 4
  UNION
  SELECT NULL drawid,NULL contact, NULL dnd, NULL name,NULL 
  numPayments,COUNT(*) as numPaidPayments ,contact PAID_CONTACT,mem.name 
  NAME_PAID  FROM mem 
   INNER JOIN payment ON (mem.drawid = payment.draw) GROUP BY 
  drawid HAVING numPaidPayments >= 4
```

I know it is because of using the NULL in query but i have less idea how to make it work without using NULL and get all non blank results ..

When i dont use NULL i get repeated results .

i am stuck here !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `as` between NULL and the rowname.

[image]

Comment: User "" instead NULL. `"" as test` like this.